# Text on HTML Canvas is only showing when page is reloaded

Tags: html, typescript, html5-canvas

I have the following code

```js
    public draw() : void
    {
        const x : number = this.ctx.canvas.width * this.x_percentage;
        const y : number = this.ctx.canvas.height * this.y_percentage;
        const width : number = this.ctx.canvas.width * this.width_percentage;
        const height : number = this.ctx.canvas.height * this.height_percentage;
        const text_margin : number = 10;

        this.ctx.font = "7vh " + this.font_name;
        this.ctx.textAlign="center"; 
        this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.fill_color;
        this.ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.text_color;
        this.ctx.fillText(this.text, x + width / 2, y + height / 2, width - text_margin); 
    }
```

This code is being called every frame, however, the text isn't appearing until I manually reload the page. What could be causing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVKwz.gif) behavior?

Comment: Please turn your code into a runnable snippet.

Comment: Without the full render cycle it is impossible to know as it could be any number of things. The canvas 2D context `ctx` is a global state so make sure something is not changing the context state to make it disappear the second time it is rendered. Eg Aloha, the transform, comp mode, filter, clip....